# Переопределение операции ++ c++

Tags: c++

не получается сделать переопределение ++ как движение по списку. Помогите пожалуйста исправить проблему

```
  struct Elem
{
    int data; 
    Elem * next, *prev;
};

class List 
{
    Elem * Head, *Tail;
    int Count;
public:
List() 
{
    Head = Tail = NULL;
    Count = 0;
};

~List() { DelAll(); };

void Del(int pos)
{

    if (pos == 0)
    {
        cout << "Input position: ";
        cin >> pos;
    }

    if (pos < 1 || pos > Count)
    {
        cout << "Incorrect position !!!\n";
        return;
    }
    int i = 1;

    Elem * Del = Head;

    while (i < pos)
    {
        Del = Del->next;
        i++;
    }

    Elem * PrevDel = Del->prev;

    Elem * AfterDel = Del->next;


    if (PrevDel != 0 && Count != 1)
        PrevDel->next = AfterDel;

    if (AfterDel != 0 && Count != 1)
        AfterDel->prev = PrevDel;

    if (pos == 1)
        Head = AfterDel;
    if (pos == Count)
        Tail = PrevDel;
    delete Del;

    Count--;
}

void DelAll( )
{
    while (Count != 0)
        Del(1);
};

void AddTail(int n)
{ 
    Elem * temp = new Elem;
    temp->next = 0;
    temp->data = n;
    temp->prev = Tail;

    if (Tail != 0)
        Tail->next = temp;

    if (Count == 0)
        Head = Tail = temp;
    else
        Tail = temp;

    Count++;
};

Elem * temp = Head;
void Print() 
{
    cout << temp->data ;
    temp++;
    cout << temp->data;
};

List & operator ++ (int)
{
     temp = temp->next;
}

};

int main()
{
    List L;
    L.AddTail(1);
    L.AddTail(2);
    L.AddTail(3);
    L.AddTail(4);
    L.Print();

    L.DelAll();
    
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> List operator ++ ()
> ```

```
List & operator ++ (List &temp, int)
```

и в конец

```
return temp;
```

---

А может так

```
List & operator ++ (int)
{
  temp = temp->next;
  return *this;
}
```

---

https://ideone.com/LMoNo8

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct List
{
  List *next = 0;
};

List & operator ++ (List &x, int)
{
  x = *x.next;
  return x;
}

int main()
{
  List *lst = new List();
  lst->next = new List();
  
  cout << lst << ' ' << lst->next << endl;

  (*lst)++;
  cout << lst << ' ' << lst->next << endl;

  // Это упадёт
  //(*lst)++;
  //cout << lst << endl;

  List lst2;
  lst2.next = new List();

  cout << &lst2 << ' ' << lst2.next << endl;

  lst2++;
  cout << &lst2 << ' ' << lst2.next << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

```
0x555ab83aae70 0x555ab83aae90
0x555ab83aae70 0
0x7ffe1772b5e0 0x555ab83abec0
0x7ffe1772b5e0 0
```

Comment: Пишет: Дополнительный параметр постфиксной формы "operator++" должен иметь тип int

Comment: ну раз пишет, почему вы не исправляете? `List & operator ++ (int)`

Comment: Тогда temp перестаёт видеть

Comment: Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Код внутри класса или снаружи? Показывай тогда больше кода в вопросе. Возможно, надо `return *this;` добавить в твою версию.

Comment: снаружи класса.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕрмолаев, `List & operator ++ (List &temp, int)` B return не забудь.

Comment: пишет слишком много параметров

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕрмолаев, всё работает: https://ideone.com/LMoNo8

Comment: Спасибо,вы мне очень помогли разобраться во всём!!!

Comment: А возможно этот список сделать двунаправленным?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЕрмолаев, я писал пример перегрузки оператора, а не реализации списка. Тут ещё и память течёт.